# Menu items won't line up underneath each other

Tags: html, css

I need some CSS help. I am trying to modify a phpBB style (Absolution) to include a new drop down item. You can see it here:

http://herb-talk.com/

I want the Products drop down on the navigation bar to imitate the Search drop down. It mostly does because I copied and pasted the code for the Search drop down. But items 1 and 2 are on the same line when you hover over it. I want Herbs 'n Seeds to be underneath Herb Kit.

I've used my usual tricks looking at it in Firebug and playing with settings. I figured adding display:block would do the trick but obviously it did not. I am missing something. I'd appreciate more experienced eyes as I am not a CSS guru.

Posting code is a challenge since it all comes out of phpBB's template system. Here is what works for the Search item on the menu:

```
            <li class="float-right<!-- IF SCRIPT_NAME eq 'search' --> active<!-- ENDIF -->">
                <a href="{U_SEARCH}"><img src="{T_THEME_PATH}/images/search<!-- IF S_USER_LOGGED_IN -->-drop<!-- ENDIF -->.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />{L_SEARCH}</a>
                <!-- IF S_USER_LOGGED_IN -->
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                    <ul class="drop">
                        <li><a href="{U_SEARCH_UNANSWERED}">{L_SEARCH_UNANSWERED}</a></li>
                        <!-- IF S_LOAD_UNREADS -->
                            <li><a href="{U_SEARCH_UNREAD}">{L_SEARCH_UNREAD}</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{U_SEARCH_NEW}">{L_SEARCH_NEW}</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{U_SEARCH_ACTIVE_TOPICS}">{L_SEARCH_ACTIVE_TOPICS}</a></li>
                        <!-- ENDIF -->
                    </ul>
                <!-- ENDIF -->                    
            </li>
            <li class="divider float-right"></li>
            <li class="float-right<!-- IF SCRIPT_NAME eq 'search' --> active<!-- ENDIF -->">
                <a href="{U_SEARCH}"><img src="{T_THEME_PATH}/images/search<!-- IF S_USER_LOGGED_IN -->-drop<!-- ENDIF -->.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />{L_SEARCH}</a>
                <!-- IF S_USER_LOGGED_IN -->
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                    <ul class="drop">
                        <li><a href="{U_SEARCH_UNANSWERED}">{L_SEARCH_UNANSWERED}</a></li>
                        <!-- IF S_LOAD_UNREADS -->
                            <li><a href="{U_SEARCH_UNREAD}">{L_SEARCH_UNREAD}</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{U_SEARCH_NEW}">{L_SEARCH_NEW}</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{U_SEARCH_ACTIVE_TOPICS}">{L_SEARCH_ACTIVE_TOPICS}</a></li>
                        <!-- ENDIF -->
                    </ul>
                <!-- ENDIF -->                    
            </li>
            <li class="divider float-right"></li>
```

and here is my copy and paste:

```
            <li class="float-right"><a href="http://homegrownherbalist-net.myshopify.com/collections/all">Products</a>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                <ul class="drop">
                    <li style="display:block;"><a href="http://homegrownherbalist-net.myshopify.com/collections/herb-kits" target="_blank">Herb Kits</a></li>
                    <li style="display:block;"><a href="http://homegrownherbalist-net.myshopify.com/collections/herbs-n-seeds" target="_blank">Herbs 'n Seeds</a></li>
                    <li style="display:block;"><a href="http://homegrownherbalist-net.myshopify.com/collections/books" target="_blank">Books</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Comment: Please post some code so we can actually help you with your problem, and list what you've tried so far.

Comment: you can try to add `.drop li {clear: both;}` , but i'm not sure if that is what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give `#nav ul li ul.drop` the declaration `width: auto`. Currently it's set to 200px.

```
#nav ul li ul.drop {
    background: #ebf4fc;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #cee1f3;
    display: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    //width: 200px;
    width: auto; //change here
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution seems to be adding `.drop li {clear: both;}`.

This specifies whether an element can be next to floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared) below them.

The `clear` property applies to both floating and non-floating elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear